# javascript output in automator

Tags: javascript, automator

I am trying to create a Service in Automator that writes out a formatted date string.  I have written a JavaScript that does the job, but I cannot figure out to actually get the output string from the script.  I have tried log, console.log, this.console.log, write, and a few other commands that I have found out there.  I am not experienced at JavaScript at all; I put this together piecemeal over a couple of hours.  Here is the code that I have:

```
ObjC.import('Cocoa');
rightNow = $.NSDate.date;
dtFormatter = $.NSDateFormatter.alloc.init;
dtFormatter.dateStyle = $.NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
dtFormatter.timeStyle = $.NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

formattedDate = dtFormatter.stringFromDate(rightNow);
```

I was under the impression from my reading that the final line of code would provide output, but this does not seem to be the case inside of the **Run JavaScript** Action in Automator.  When this code is run in Script Editor, the console displays the formatted date as expected.

Thank you very much for any counsel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the variable formattedDate needs to be "unwrapped" from its Objective-C packaging:

[Answered at MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=180744#p180744)

The final code is therefore:

```
ObjC.import('Cocoa');
rightNow = $.NSDate.date;
dtFormatter = $.NSDateFormatter.alloc.init;
dtFormatter.dateStyle = $.NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
dtFormatter.timeStyle = $.NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

formattedDate = dtFormatter.stringFromDate(rightNow);

 ObjC.unwrap(formattedDate)
```